# comparing array value from multidimensional array with index

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that loks lik this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => >chr1:2198584545754_genome_1000+
        [score] => 511
        [hit] => 50   

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => >chr2:2198581212154_genome_1000+
        [score] => 620
        [hit] => 80   

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => >chr3:2115151215754_genome_1000+
        [score] => 666
        [hit] => 90   

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => >chr4:2198584545754_genome_1000+
        [score] => 750
        [hit] => 50 

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => >chr5:1218455145754_genome_1000+
        [score] => 800
        [hit] => 100  

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => >chr6:1231354645454_genome_1000+
        [score] => 850
        [hit] => 110  

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => >chr7:1231213211134_genome_1000+
        [score] => 900
        [hit] => 120  

    )

 )
```

I have a foreach loop which will loop through each letter of a random sequence and use the index to give each letter a number value.
If the value of ['hit'] matches the index value of the random sequence
i want to insert a function.

I cannot figure this out. I think my problem is in callng each value of ['hit'] and comparing with index.  Does anyone know how to do this ?
thanks

Comment: Errrm... wait, what? Can you provide a little more information, what output you expect, you expect the result to be etc

Comment: sorry.. I want to grab all the ['hit'] values and then compare all them against each $index(number)if one of the ['hit'] values is the same as an index , ..do something.. e.g. echo "hello". my problem is grabbing the ['hit'] values and comparing each of them with the $index.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Can't you just do something like `foreach ($array as $sub) { if ($sub['hit'] == $index) { do_something(); } }` or am I missing somthing?

Comment: I had tried something vry similar with this earlier, and didn work as  i wanted, however this is better, sorry this answer should be obvious to me now.  Thanks, answered my q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put DaveRandom's comment into an answer (with minor amends):

```
foreach ($outerArray as $index => $innerArray)
{
    if($innerArray['hit'] === $index)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

@DaveRandom - feel free to delete or re-post this as your own answer if I'm posting out of turn here...

Answer (score 1):

```
       foreach ($array as $key) {

       if ($key['hit'] == $index)

        { 

      // you function or logic here

        } 

    }
```

Comment: has dave said similar to something